# How can I get data from different S3 buckets by AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have two AWS S3 buckets.
One bucket stores the product user log.
Another bucket stores the user attribution(ex. gender, age, etc) data.

I would like to get the user log and attribution data from these buckets and combine the data into one table.
May I know how to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Quite easy...

- Use `CREATE TABLE` to define each table, specifying the `LOCATION` of the data
- Run a query that joins both tables, using standard SQL

You can either query the data from both tables simultaneously, or you can create a new table that is the output of such a query by using `CREATE TABLE AS`.

Answer (score 1):

just create two tables by using the below method

```
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS]
 [db_name.]table_name [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment] [, ...] )]
 [COMMENT table_comment]
 [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
 [ROW FORMAT row_format]
 [STORED AS file_format] 
 [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)] ]
 [LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/[folder]/']
 [TBLPROPERTIES ( ['has_encrypted_data'='true | false',] ['classification'='aws_glue_classification',] property_name=property_value [, ...] ) ]
```

then join two tables for creating your desired result table

[AWS Docs link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)